# Understanding container-to-container security for application instances in CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I refer to the articles about container-to-container security at https://ict.swisscom.ch/2018/05/container-networking-with-cloud-foundry/ and https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html

This helps to define direct inter-application conncectivity. What I still try to find out is how the connectivity between application **instances** is working, i.e. when scaling up an application to 2 instances, how do those 2 instances see each other via the network? I tried to solve this question for a long time, as this would be very important for cluster based interactions, such as Hazelcast, using broadcast mechanisms to identify cluster members.

Is that (intra-application instance connectivity) documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that (intra-application instance connectivity) documented somewhere?

It is the same as app to app communication. Everything is just an instance connected to the container to container network. AppA & AppB, or AppA instance #1 and AppA instance #2. They're all on the container to container network.

> All Diego cells in your Cloud Foundry deployment share this overlay network. By default, each cell is allocated a /24 range that supports 254 containers per cell, one container for each of the usable IP addresses, .1 through .254.

From: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html#overlay-network

Just remember that all traffic is blocked by default, so you need to add a network policy to allow traffic over the C2C network. For talking between two apps, the `cf add-network-policy` syntax makes sense. You have a source and destination app. For app containers within the same app, the command is a little confusing because there's only one app, not a source and destination. That said, it should work just fine if you make the source and destination the same.

Ex: `cf add-network-policy my-cluster-app --destination-app my-cluster-app --protocol tcp --port 9990-10000`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot. Thanks!